# Issue updating rows c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem where I can either update by one row (and that's it) or by four at once.

The issue is with `tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tr1)` on the last two lines, comments are indicating what happens when the statement is placed there.

There will be a limit of 6, but I can't figure out why I can't update one row at a time more than once with the code I've got.

The for loops are only allowing four cells per row and no more than 4 rows (not including the initial row at start).

Can you point me in the right direction please?

C#:

```
public void addRows_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  rmvRows.Visible = true;

  // rows
  for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < 4; rowCount++ )
  {
    tr1 = new TableRow();
    // cells
    for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < 4; cellCount++)
    {
      tc1 = new TableCell();
      tb1 = new TextBox();
      tb1.ID = "tbID" + cellCount.ToString();
      tc1.Controls.Add(tb1);
      tr1.Cells.Add(tc1);
    }
    tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tr1);// will add four more rows
  }
  tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tr1)// adds one one but no more 
}
```

Comment: your rowCount is < 4 and cellCount is < 4, obviously it wont allow you more than those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tr1);// will add four more rows
```

is within a `for` loop  that is running 4 times (from 0 to 3):

```
for (int rowCount = 0; rowCount < 4; rowCount++ )
{
    tr1 = new TableRow();
    /* code omitted */
    tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tr1);// will add four more rows
}
```

The line itself only adds one row each time it is called, but it is getting called 4 times. Therefore, the table has 4 additional rows after the `for` loop's execution.

As for your second line:

```
tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tr1)// adds one one but no more
```

This is outside of any loop, so, like any other normal code, it only executes once. Since it only executes once, it only adds one row.

Additionally, since `tr1` is not changed after the `for` loop, the final row added by that last line is going to be a duplicate of whatever the last row created by the loop was.

Comment: Ah that would explain it, cheers - will accept when timer is up. Need to sort it to add per button click now with a limit of whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tr1)
```

Only adds one row regardless were it is called because tr1 is just one row.

The AddAt will only allow one row to be added at a curtain position.

The AddAt used in the loop should work just fine.

Hope that helps!